# Get a list of domains from a table via regex

Tags: php, regex

I have list of domains in table with more info and

```
<td>example1.com</td>
<td>example2.org</td>
<td>example3.com</td>
<td>example4.com</td>
```

I need get .com domains using a regex. I tried to use something like :

```
'<td>(.............).com'
```

But what can I write instead of dots? What do I need to use?

I need get the data between the tags: `<td>domain.com</td> -> domain.com`

```
'<td>([^<]+\.com)</td>'
```

- it's more better, but i need get without tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/209605

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$html = '<td>example1.com</td>
<td>example2.org</td>
<td>example3.com</td>
<td>example4.com</td>';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/<td>(.*?.com)<\/td>/i', $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

prints:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "example1.com"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "example3.com"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "example4.com"
}
```

Comment: i don't need replace it, i need get it

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
'<td>([^<]+\.com)</td>'
```

but you shouldn't use regular expressions to parse html.

Comment: but i need only .com domines, but in table i have much more another information

Comment: @user2368299 domains, not domines - look at the edit in your post

Comment: @user2368299: "but in table i have much more": that's not part of the stated requirements.  fix your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use look aheads and look behinds if you want to capture something but make sure it's surrounded by something else. Here we're capturing `.com` only.

```
<?php

$html = '<td>example1.com</td>
<td>example2.org</td>
<td>example3.com</td>
<td>example4.com</td>'; 

$pattern = "!(?<=<td>).*\.com*(?=</td>)!";
preg_match_all($pattern,$html,$matches);

$urls = $matches[0];

print_r($urls);

?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => example1.com
    [1] => example3.com
    [2] => example4.com
)
```